# psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "ON"

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

This one has been driving me nuts. I looked online.
My database is Postgres 9.5.4. 
I'm using python 3 and psycopg2 2.7.1

I am getting the following error

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "ON"
LINE 2:                       ON CONFLICT do nothing
```

And my code is :

```
    try:
        c = db.cursor()
        c.execute("""INSERT INTO my_table (id, name, tstmp)
                  VALUES (%s,%s,%s)
                  ON CONFLICT do nothing""",
                  (id, name, tstmp))
    finally:
        c.close()
```

Is `ON` not supported by psycopg2 or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How sure are you that you're using 9.5? `SELECT version()` from your cursor.